# Is there currently an easy way to root Sony Xperia S with stock ICS 4.0.4 ROM?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, bootloader, stock-android, sony-xperia-s

I'm looking for an easy way, which doesn't need Unlocking bootloader or flashing Roms, just like root solution for SE 2011 devices (one click). It's because I currently use my Xperia S for development purposes and can't afford bricking it! please tell me if there is a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Potential close voters: [We don't close vote rooting questions as duplicates any more](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/790/should-we-revisit-our-how-do-i-root-x-policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, at last, the mighty user of XDA, Bin4ary, has released a very nice and easy toolkit to root ICS JB roms of most sony phones, including Xperia S.

I used the tool and easily rooted my phone. Very fast and painless. No need to flash or unlock bootloader or anything.

If you are also interested, this is the page on XDA:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460

Answer (score 6):

There's a guide on [Rooting Xperia S ICS and GB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1742992) over at XDAs. Not having any XPeria device, I cannot verify -- but the comments on the thread confirm it working. It does not even require the bootloader to be unlocked.

### Requirements for that method:

- Windows
- Net framework 3.5 or later

### Preparation:

1. Application Settings: [Unknown sources] checked {Allowed}
2. Application Settings: Development [USB debugging] checked {Allowed}
3. Application Settings: Development [Stay awake] checked {Allowed}
4. Settings -> Display settings [Screen timeout] Set to 30 minutes
   **If your screen goes off just once then you won’t be able to return to the installation properly. Very important!!**
   Please think about your battery and try to keep the display brightness to a minimum.
5. Please use a regular picture for the background. Do not use the default live wallpaper.
6. Charge the Xperia S’s battery to 80%.
7. Use the Generic CH (1257-3740) XPERIA S LT26i ROM (6.1.A.0.452).
   Can be found here along with the latest FLASTOOL link: [XDA FileServer](http://www.xdafileserver.nl/index.php?dir=Sony+%28Ericsson%29%2FSE+Xperia+S+%28LT26i%29%2FSTOCK+ROMS)
8. Net framework 3.5 or later
9. Gingerbread [part 1](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?004x3fnftr32135) and [part 2](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?23e963o6a8dq8rg)

It also mentions a [Root Toolkit](http://www.mediafire.com/?o1v2o6afuoc1w33).

### Installation Process:

1. Flash Gingerbread firmware wiping data and cache only if you are not on gingerbread
2. Run Step 1.bat
3. Install ICE CREAM SANDWICH without wiping anything
4. Run step 2.bat

> To enter CWM recovery you have to tap on sony logo at start few times.
>
> If it does not root properly first time run it again
>
> Thanks to Bin4ry for the files

### Alternative: Unlocking the Bootloader

An alternative method involves the SDK, and is described at [AndroidPit](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/473599/) (German; Google Translate 2 English [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F473599%2FAnleitung-Unlock-und-Root-fuer-euer-Sony-Xperia-S)). this method, however, involves unlocking the bootloader -- so be aware of Sony's harsh politics when it comes to warranty in this case.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have currently seen this tutorial. I mentioned in my question that I want a way without any need to flash other ROMs than my current ICS stock rom.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find such solution -- so I thought it would be better than nothing. With some luck somebody else finds a more convenient solution we all have missed -- but if not, you at least have two fall-back solutions noted here. I'd rather love if root came pre-installed, like with our desktop systems...

Comment: Added variant #3 -- found a one-click solution for you :)

Comment: thanks again, unfortunately that wasn't for "Xperia S", but for Xperia Arc (my previous phone) from Xperia 2011 series. I'm aware of this site rules and I researched really hard before posting my question here, but found nothing, just some tuts like your answers.

Comment: Ouch -- OK, sorry for that; if you say it isn't applyable to your Xperia S, I better remove it from the answer to avoid confusion. On the page it said "Xperia Arc S" (to keep the link for reference: [PocketPC.CH](http://www.pocketpc.ch/sony-ericsson-xperia-arc-root-rom/159013-root-fuer-ice-cream-sandwich-geraete-oneclicksolution-bin4ry.html)). Maybe you should include with your question what sources you already checked -- you didn't say so, so it's hard not to post anything you already found yourself ;)