# Is there way to switch between proxy settings on ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, settings, proxy, sony-xperia-s

I have an Xperia S running 4.0.4. I often need to switch to a proxy for accessing a test server. I can do this fine by modifying my Wifi connection, selecting to show advanced options and then entering the proxy information manually.

The problem is that if I then need to disable the proxy, ICS 'forgets' the settings so I have to enter them manually each time. I need the proxy to work with Adobe Edge Inspect and so browser-specific proxy options are not the answer.

Is there a reputable third-party app which will let me switch between proxies for the current network connection?

Answer (score 1):

Just try [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en)

This app need root permission and IPTABLES support.

It's a full feature proxy application including support for HTTP/Socks proxy types, global/individual proxy mode, multiple profiles.

Binding configuration to WIFI's ssid or mobile connection is also supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app which is perfect for your situation

> [Wifi Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kman.WifiManager)

You can also try [Proxy Server Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.proxyserverpro)

*Note: These apps do not ask for root permissions. But if you're supposed to have root permission, which you don't in your stock ROM, you may want to unlock the bootloader to have root access. See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28441/23379) for rooting details.*

Comment: rooting Xperia S 4.0.4 does NOT need unlocking bootloader, as answered by me on the question you have linked to.

Comment: well, the suggested app does what you need do yes? :)

Comment: I'm not the one who asked for the app :)

Comment: [okay](http://alltheragefaces.com/img/faces/large/okay-okay-l.png) :)

Comment: @Sid what do you mean by 'if you're supposed to have root permission?'

Comment: @yrajabi I would actually quite like to get rid of the animation provided by O2 as part of the boot process. Does that require unlocking the bootloader?

Comment: @Sid When adding a proxy in Wifi Manager it tells me that only the web browser and no other applications will use it. I need it to work for all applications

Comment: @codecowboy it means if you have root permission in your *originally unrooted* device. And let's see if others have solutions for you.

Comment: @Sid nobody else has added comments and Proxy Server pro is a server and not what I need.